# I'm dealing with slow website page loading, can the N+1 problem happen to the service provider?

Tags: laravel

the following is the service provider code, what I experienced was about N + 1 problem because after checking using the clockwork there was a Query. Here I include a picture of the clockwork results and the coding of the service provider:

[image]

dibawah ini coding service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $appName = config('app.name');

        if (preg_match_all('/\b(\w)/', strtoupper($appName), $value))
            $acronymAppName = implode('', $value[0]);

        $view
            ->with('appName', $appName)
            ->with('acronymAppName', $acronymAppName);

        if (strpos(url()->current(), 'admin') !== false && strpos(url()->current(), 'print') === false) {
            $logo = General::where('type', 'logo')->first();
            $path = $logo->content;

            $unprocessedPesanan = ViewPesanan::whereNotIn('status_pesanan_id', [
                Pesanan::STATUS_SELESAI,
                Pesanan::STATUS_DIBATALKAN,
            ])
                ->groupBy('status_pesanan_id')
                ->get([
                    'status_pesanan_id',
                    DB::raw("SUM(1) as total"),
                ])
                ->pluck('total', 'status_pesanan_id');

            $totalUnprocessedPesanan = $unprocessedPesanan->sum();

            $view
                ->with('logo', $path)
                ->with('unprocessedPesanan', $unprocessedPesanan)
                ->with('totalUnprocessedPesanan', $totalUnprocessedPesanan);
        }

        if (strpos(url()->current(), 'admin') === false) {
            $unreadPesanan = ViewPesanan::where('pelanggan_id', Auth::id())
                ->whereNull('read_at')
                ->groupBy('status_pesanan_id')
                ->get([
                    'status_pesanan_id',
                    DB::raw("SUM(1) as total"),
                ])
                ->pluck('total', 'status_pesanan_id');

            $totalUnreadPesanan = $unreadPesanan->sum();

            $view
                ->with('unreadPesanan', $unreadPesanan)
                ->with('totalUnreadPesanan', $totalUnreadPesanan);
        }

        if (strpos(url()->current(), 'print') !== false) {
            $alamat = General::where('type', 'alamat')->first()->content;
            $telepon = General::where('type', 'telepon')->first()->content;

            $view
                ->with('alamat', $alamat)
                ->with('telepon', $telepon);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This isn't an N+1 problem as the query isn't changing. The issue here is that the view composer is being called for every view that is getting rendered.

Comment: Is the data generated from this composer getting used in multiple views or just a single one?

Comment: this is running for every view that is rendered ... a single "page" could be many views that have to be rendered do to includes and extending layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must specify the specific "View" in which you need data in the "ComposerServiceProvider". Otherwise, the requests that are described will be executed for each "view".

You now have all the view "*"

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
```

So do not specify a specific view correctly.

```
public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer(
            'web.backend.layout.header', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\NotificationComposer'
        );

        view()->composer(
            'web.backend.layout.header', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\CategoryComposer'
        );
    }
```